# What is the cleanest way to create a new column based on a conditional of an existing column?

Tags: pandas, calculated-columns

In pandas I currently have a data frame containing a column of strings: {Urban, Suburban, Rural}. The column I would like to create is conditional of the first column (i.e. Urban, Suburban, Rural are associated with the corresponding colors) {Coral, Skyblue, Gold}

I tried copying the first column and then using .replace but my new column seems to return NaN values now instead of the colors.

```
new_column = merge_table["type"]
merge_table["color"] = new_column

color_df = merge_table["color"].replace({'Urban': 'Coral', 'Suburban': 'Skyblue', 'Rural': 'Gold'})



data = pd.DataFrame({'City Type': type,
                           'Bubble Color': color_df    
                          })
data.head()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
 merge_table['New col']=merge_table["color"].replace({'Urban': 'Coral', 'Suburban': 'Skyblue', 'Rural': 'Gold'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay. in the future, its worth typing the codes using 'Code Samples' so that we can view your code easier.

Lots of areas can improve your code. Firstly you do the entire thing in one line:

```
merge_table["color"] = merge_table["type"].map(mapping_dictionary)
```

Series.map() is around 4 times faster than Series.replace() for your information.

also other tips:

1. never use type as a variable name, use something more specific like city_type. type is already a standard built-in method

   ```
   data = pd.DataFrame({'City Type': city_type, 'Bubble Color': color_df})
   ```
2. if make a copy of a column, use:

   ```
   a_series = df['column_name'].copy()
   ```

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. Will also take your recommendation to not use 'type' as variable name!